# Bicep - create credentials for Managed Identity for use in LinkedService

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I am attempting to re-create an Azure Data Factory using Bicep, and specifically i am trying to user a User Assigned Managed Identity for a linked service to an Azure SQL Database.

I am able to create the ua MI by doing the following -

```
resource uami 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
    name: uamiName
    location: location

  }
```

This gets successfully attached to the data factory upon build.

Next i am trying to associate that UA MI to the database connection i am making in the Linked Services section. In the front end its like selected 'User Assigned Managed Identity' and selecting the creds ( or create new). I am trying to do this via Bicep and In order to do this, i first needs credentials - I can't find anywhere in Bicep to create these credentials.

[image]

I see lots of old references to Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials - but i can't seem to find that.

Appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Comment: can you export the ARM template from an ADF with it setup and then decompile to Bicep to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found much documentation neither.
I've created a credential from data factory studio then export the ARM template. The bicep equivalent looks like that:

```bicep
param location string
param uamiName string
param dataFactoryName string

// Create the managed identity
resource uami 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
  name: uamiName
  location: location
}

// assuming the data factory already exists
resource dataFactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' existing = {
  name: dataFactoryName
}

// Create the credentials
resource credentials 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials@2018-06-01' = {
  name: uami.name
  parent: dataFactory
  properties: {
    type: 'ManagedIdentity'
    typeProperties: {
      resourceId: uami.id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldnt see 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials@2018-06-01' in the docs, did you find it?

Comment: Not in thee doc, but by exporting the ARM template from data factory studio